# Can't databind a dropdown list

Tags: php, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I'm having issues databinding a dropdown list. I'm following a MVC structure and this is how I did it.

Here is a function from my Model layer:

```
function GetTillverkare()
{
    $data = array();
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    $query = "Select Namn from Tillverkare";
    if(!$sql = mysql_query($query)) {
        throw new exception("Error: Can not execute the query.");
    } else {
        $num = mysql_num_rows($sql);
        if($num>0)
        {
            for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
            {
                $data[$i] = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;

}
```

Here is the code from my Controller layer:

```
$displayResults = new Sok() //Sok is my model class.

$GetTillverkare = $displayResults->getTillverkare(); 
//I am able to print the $GetTillverkare so there is no problem with getting the data.
```

Here is my View layer

```
Fabrikat:<br /> <select name="Tillverkare_search" id="Tillverkare_search">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Pick</option>
        <option value="<?php echo $GetTillverkare ?>"</option>

    </select><br/>
```

I don't get any error, but it doesn't display data o the dropdown list. It's empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model function returns array so you can't print array by echo , if each index of array
is element of this list try to print this way

```
for($i=0;$<sizeof($GetTillverkere;$i++){
 echo "<option value='".$GetTillverkere[$i]."'>".$GetTillverkere[$i]."</option>";
 }
```

and you also have unclosed html tag in second option tag , and you try to print name to value of option but no in between tags which is the visible part of this tag

Comment: I tried it, but only got"Array, Array, Array" as result on the dropdown list.. Somehow the name of the array didn't display..

Comment: When I print out `$GetTillverkare` I get *Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Advanced Bionics [tillverkare] => Advanced Bionics ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Cochlear [tillverkare] => Cochlear ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Med-El [tillverkare] => Med-El ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Med-El [tillverkare] => Med-El ) )*